# <pre><code> block displays one fewer trailing line feeds than it should

Tags: bug, markdown

When creating a code block in markdown with trailing line feeds, it displays correctly in edit mode, but after saving the edit I can briefly see it the same way, then the last line disappears.

**Example:**

This Python quine has a trailing new line. In edit mode, it displays, but not after that on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. It displays fine here, for some reason. Also, I'm fairly certain it used to work, as I've used blocks like these several times, but I just saw this bug today.

Markdown:

```
<pre><code>_='_=%r;print _%%_\n';print _%_

</code></pre>
```

Displayed:

```
_='_=%r;print _%%_\n';print _%_
```

[**See bug in action**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99328/34718)

In case the post linked above is changed later, I took some screenshots:

> [image]

After saving edit:

> [image]

**Notes:**

- I tested this with Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE 11.
- This bug doesn't occur in Firefox, but occurs in the others.
- The "flicker" from correct to wrong only happens in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Looks like it's the highlighting that strips the trailing new line (or not actually stripping it, but the `<span>` the highlighting inserts collapses it unless it's followed by another—no idea why though). The edit page doesn't have highlighting, so no issue there.